# speed of FDE with SSD

Tags: performance, encryption, ssd

Anyone have any opinions on using solid state drives with full disk encryption (software-based), such as BitLocker? Not looking for benchmarks so much as personal experiences people have had, in addition to suggestions, provisos, etc. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that combination, worked fine, no suggestions or caveats though.

Which is a good thing right? :)